# Fastest way to parse a Word document containing Transcript text into Excel columns

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, document, text-to-column

I have multiple word document files, each containing transcript text like below (paragraph marks not shown):

```
Some Title1              ' <--- Some title ending with paragraph mark
(Apr 3, 2023 - 9:00am)  ' <--- Date - time ending with paragraph mark
(Interviewee: Harry) ' <--- Interviewee name to pick to only add interviewee lines (name and text) to outrow array.
                        ' <--- blank line ending with paragraph mark
(00:00:00 - 00:00:02)   ' <--- timestamp ending with paragraph mark

Harry: Okay, thank you. ' <--- Speaker: Text ending with paragraph mark

(00:00:02 - 00:00:06)
Tom: Hi, Harry, hello. Are you okay?

(00:00:06 - 00:00:09)
Harry: Yeah, I'm good, thank you. How are you doing? Happy Monday to you.

(00:00:09 - 00:00:12)
Tom: It's a nice Monday today, so it's quite bright for a change.
```

As there are many doc files, I would like to copy the whole content (all paragraphs) from each doc file into an excel sheet `Sheet2`, appending each content to the last non-blank row. Once done, I would like to use the TextToColumns feature in Excel to split the text into individual columns as shown:

| Title | DateTime | TimeStamp | Speaker | Text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Some Title1 | (Apr 3, 2023 - 9:00am) | (00:00:00 - 00:00:02) | Harry | Okay, thank you. |
|  |  | (00:00:06 - 00:00:09) | Harry | Yeah, I'm good, thank you. How are you doing? Happy Monday to you. |
| Some Title2 | (Apr 5, 2023 - 19:00pm) | (00:00:00 - 00:00:04) | Jill | I am doing fine. |
|  |  | (00:00:06 - 00:00:12) | Jill | I'm busy. |

...

Currently i am only able to loop and copy paste the docs contents to sheet. Once consolidated in the sheet, I would like to transpose this content into the table as shown above. Also, if there is a way to collect all the doc contents into an array or ado recordset, then transfer array/recordset content directly to sheet in one go, that would speed up code and save some time.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ParseTranscriptToExcelSheet()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Dim wdApp As Object ' Word application
    Dim wdDoc As Object ' Word document
    Dim tbl As Object   ' Table
    Dim para As Object  ' Paragraph
    Dim row As Integer  ' Row index for the table
    Dim i As Long
    Dim oFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim vSelectedItem As Variant
    
    ' declare worksheets
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) ' contains button to run code
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
    
    ' Add a header row to the worksheet 2
    ws2.Range("A1:E1").Value = Array("Title", "DateTime", "Timestamp", "Speaker", "Text")
    
    ' Initialize the row index for the table
    row = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1
    
    ' Open the Word document containing the transcript
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
        
    If wdApp Is Nothing Then
        Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    
    With wdApp
        .Visible = False
    End With
            
'    ReDim sContent(1 To 1)
    Set oFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With oFileDialog
        .Title = "Select Word Files"
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Filters.Add "Word files", "*.doc*", 1
        If .Show = -1 Then
            ws2.Activate
            For Each vSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
                Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(vSelectedItem)
                With wdDoc
'                    sContent(UBound(sContent)) = .Content.formattedtext.text
                    .Content.Copy
                    ws2.Cells(row, 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    DoEvents
                    .Close savechanges:=False
                    row = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1
                End With
'                ReDim Preserve sContent(1 To UBound(sContent) + 1) As String
            Next vSelectedItem
'            ReDim Preserve sContent(1 To UBound(sContent) - 1) As String
                
        Else
            MsgBox "No files selected"
        End If
    
    End With
    
    
    wdApp.Quit
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set wdApp = Nothing
    Set ws1 = Nothing
    Set ws2 = Nothing
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: So what code have you tried so far "to transpose this content into the table as shown above"? Please post the code you have tried so for this and advise the specific problem you have with that code that you would like help with.

Comment: `Split(wdDoc.Range.Text,vbcr)` will give you an array of the lines in the document - try looping over that and populating the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ParseTranscriptToExcelSheet()
    Dim wdApp As Object ' Word application
    Dim wdDoc As Object ' Word document
    Dim allFiles As Collection, f, txt As String, arr, el, ub As Long
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet, nextRow As Long, x As Long, arr2, ln
    
    Set allFiles = SelectedFiles()
    If allFiles.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
    ws2.Range("A1:E1").Value = Array("Title", "DateTime", "Timestamp", "Speaker", "Text")
    nextRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1
    
    Set wdApp = GetWordApp()
    
    For Each f In allFiles                     'loop over selected files
        Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(f)    'open files
        txt = wdDoc.Range.Text                 'read content
        wdDoc.Close False
        arr = Split(txt, vbCr)                 'get array of lines/paras
        ub = UBound(arr)
        If ub > 0 Then
            ws2.Cells(nextRow, "A").Value = arr(0)  'fill the "header" info
            ws2.Cells(nextRow, "B").Value = arr(1)
            For x = 2 To UBound(arr)                'process rest of lines
                ln = Trim(arr(x))
                If ln Like "(*)" Then                       'timestamp?
                    ws2.Cells(nextRow, "C").Value = ln 
                ElseIf ln Like "*:*" Then                   'speaker text?           
                    arr2 = Split(ln, ":", 2)
                    ws2.Cells(nextRow, "D").Value = arr2(0) 'speaker
                    ws2.Cells(nextRow, "E").Value = arr2(1) 'content
                    nextRow = nextRow + 1
                End If
            Next x
        End If
        nextRow = nextRow + 1
    Next f
End Sub

'return a Collection of user-selected Word files
Function SelectedFiles() As Collection
    Dim f
    Set SelectedFiles = New Collection
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .Title = "Select one or more Word Files"
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Filters.Add "Word files", "*.doc*", 1
        If .Show = -1 Then
            For Each f In .SelectedItems
                SelectedFiles.Add f
            Next f
        End If
    End With
End Function

'Get a running Word instance, or start a new instance
Function GetWordApp() As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetWordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If GetWordApp Is Nothing Then
        Set GetWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'assuming this works ok...
    End If
    GetWordApp.Visible = True
End Function
```

EDIT: here's a version which populates an array and writes to the Excel sheet at the end

```vb
Sub ParseTranscriptToExcelSheet_Array()
    Dim wdApp As Object ' Word application
    Dim wdDoc As Object ' Word document
    Dim allFiles As Collection, f, txt As String, arr, el, ub As Long
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet, x As Long, arr2, ln, arrOut(), outRow As Long
    
    Set allFiles = SelectedFiles()
    If allFiles.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
    ws2.Cells.ClearContents 'for testing....
    
    ws2.Range("A1:E1").Value = Array("Title", "DateTime", "Timestamp", "Speaker", "Text")
   
    ReDim arrOut(1 To 20000, 1 To 5) 'array for output; guessing at max size....
    outRow = 1
    
    Set wdApp = GetWordApp()
    
    For Each f In allFiles                     'loop over selected files
        Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(f)    'open files
        txt = wdDoc.Range.Text                 'read content
        wdDoc.Close False
        arr = Split(txt, vbCr)                 'get array of lines/paras
        ub = UBound(arr)
        If ub > 0 Then
            arrOut(outRow, 1) = arr(0)  'fill the "header" info
            arrOut(outRow, 2) = arr(1)
            For x = 2 To UBound(arr)            'process rest of lines
                ln = Trim(arr(x))
                If ln Like "(*)" Then           'timestamp?
                    arrOut(outRow, 3) = ln
                ElseIf ln Like "*:*" Then       'speaker text?
                    arr2 = Split(ln, ":", 2)
                    arrOut(outRow, 4) = arr2(0) 'speaker
                    arrOut(outRow, 5) = arr2(1) 'content
                    outRow = outRow + 1
                End If
            Next x
        End If
        outRow = outRow + 1
    Next f
    
    'any content to write?
    If outRow > 1 Then ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp). _
           Offset(1).Resize(outRow, 5).Value = arrOut
    
End Sub
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, is there some memory structure (like ADO recordset) in which the transformations can be done and stored/appended for each doc, in tabular form, then dumping the entire table into excel sheet in one go? currently, the code works, but takes some time when i looped through 12 doc files (10,205 rows and text column with huge paragraphs of 500 words or more). I guess, it has to do with the constant writing to the excel sheet.

Comment: See my edit above...

Comment: Excellent. Is it possible to make the array dynamic?

Comment: Yes but I think it's more trouble than it's worth.  A 2D array can only be resized on the last ("column") dimension, so you'd need to flip  to something like `arrOut(1 To 5, 1 To 20000)` and then transpose that before you place it on the worksheet.  You can try that if you feel it necessary.

Comment: just one question: In docs, there is no way to automatically determine who is a interviewer and who is interviewee. If i want to keep only interviewee lines in table (see edits to original table), i have manually added `(Interviewee: name)` e.g. `(Interviewee: Harry)` to top of each doc after the `(date-time)`. I am planning to submit this change to reporting team who generate these docs. How can i pick up interviewee and only keep Interviewee lines in outrow array? This will also reduce number of rows in Excel sheet where this data gets dumped. Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: It's not useful to folks coming along later if you use your question for "rolling updates"  and continued incremental questions.  The original question has disappeared, and the following comments/answers may no longer apply.  Maybe post a new question with the code you're using, and the "old" and "new" doc formats, so they can be more-easily compared.